# create custom views for django-tagging

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tagging

I'm currently working on **django tagging**. 
I want to retrieve all the entries from my given model which are associated with a particular tag.
But i don't want to use the generic views. So how should i design my views to get this done and how can i render this in my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering Element is your class from your model.

**In your view**

```
from django.db import models
from tagging.fields import TagField
from tagging.models import Tag

def myView(request,slug,tag){
   user = request.user
   element = Element.objects.get(slug=slug)
   #getting all tags added on the given element
   tags = Tag.objects.get_for_object(element)
   #getting all elements containing the given tag
   taggedElement = Element.objects.filter(tags__contains=tag)

  template = "elements/elements.html";

    context = {
        'taggedElement':taggedElement ,
        'tags':tags,
        'user':user,
    }

  return render_to_response( template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
}
```

**Then in your template (elements.html)**

```
{% for tag in tags%}
<div class="tag">{{tag}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```